# Why this call from JSF to Hibernate controller returns javax.el.MethodNotFoundException?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf, netbeans, xhtml

I'm trying to execute a query to a mySQL database through Hibernate, for that I've developed a simple JSF page to introduce two words and search by these fields, but when I try to execute the method which make the query, I go an exception: **javax.el.MethodNotFoundException**

Here is the JSF page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Plans search</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Plan Search</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectOneRadio id="searchBy" value="#{myController.searchBy}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="By User" itemValue="User Name"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="By Plan" itemValue="Plan Name"></f:selectItem>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
        <h:inputText label="Name" id="name" value="#{myController.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:inputText label="Surname" id="surname" value="#{myController.surname}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton id="search" type="submit" value="Search" action="#{myController.userPlans}"></h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
    <div><h:outputText value="#{myController.name} was invited to the following plans"></h:outputText></div>

    <h:dataTable id="plansid" value="#{myController.userPlans}" var="plans" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Plans Name"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{plans.planName}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

and the code for myController is:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyController {

MyHelper helper;
DataModel listUSer;
private DataModel userPlans;
private String name;
private String surname;
Users user;
private String searchBy;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of myController
 */
public MyController() {
    helper = new MyHelper();
}

public MyController(String name, String surname) {
    helper = new FeverHelper();
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

void recreateModel() {
    setUserPlans(null);
}

/**
 * @return the searchBy
 */
public String getSearchBy() {
    return searchBy;
}

/**
 * @param searchBy the searchBy to set
 */
public void setSearchBy(String searchBy) {
    this.searchBy = searchBy;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the surname
 */
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

/**
 * @param surname the surname to set
 */
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

/**
 * @return the userPlans
 */
public DataModel getUserPlans() {
    if (userPlans == null) {
        setUserPlans(new ListDataModel(helper.getUserPlans(getName(), getSurname())));
    }
    return userPlans;
}

/**
 * @param userPlans the userPlans to set
 */
public void setUserPlans(DataModel userPlans) {
    this.userPlans = userPlans;
}
```

}

Appareantly is well defined, isn't it?

I'm just working over the index.xhtml file, without templates, or other padding stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify the component that fails. From a glance, I think it is the

```
<h:commandButton id="search" type="submit" value="Search" action="#{myController.userPlans}"></h:commandButton>
```

(if it is not, it is your fault by no providing a detailed description of your problem).

An actio method is not a property, so you need one of these methods defined in your controller class:

```
public String userPlans()...

public void userPlans()...  // no navigation
```

Comment: I think both of you are wrong, because that call myController.userPlans has to call automatically to the getter method for that field. 

So If I have a field named "userPlans" and I have defined the getter and setter, that call, myController.userPlans should run the getUserPlans.

@SJuan76, you are right that component is which it fails.

Comment: Not for an action method. You are thinking about property EL expressions, which are a different thing.

Comment: Sorry for that. So could you guide me to fix the error please? I'd thank that. Because I thought that it was well-coded...

Comment: Define the function as explained in my post. You still need the `getUserPlans` so your page can get the property to show it.

Comment: Ok, I understood how JSF works at least for my example. ;) Thanks a lot, this is the right answer.

Comment: One last thing... don't put logic in properties (`get/set` methods), they are called many times during the processing of a request.

Comment: Thanks, thats true, I noticed some processing executing the inital getUserPlans. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Your search command button in your XHTML is pointing to #{myController.userPlans} but there is no action method on your bean called userPlans()

Comment: Do your lookup logic in a method called public void userPlans(). Then create the datamodel from the results and set it